# Bxslider Setting Height

Tags: css, height, bxslider

So I just started using bxslider.

I however I'm having issues setting the size of the slider.  Naturally it takes the height of the largest element (I think).  How do I set it to a fixed height, say 200px?

Answer (score 25):

You can add following css.

```
.bx-wrapper, .bx-viewport {
    height: 200px !important; //provide height of slider
}
```

Check out this fiddle..[bxslider](http://jsfiddle.net/HyQvF/)

Answer (score 15):

Why not style the elements?
If you set a fix height for the wrapper you could get in trouble with overflows and positioning.

If you are using lists:

```
.bx-wrapper ul li { height: 200px; }
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to set all 3 elements involved with the height of the image displayed which are the main container, the inner container and the images themselves...

**like so:**

```
.bx-wrapper, .bx-viewport, .bx-wrapper img {height: 500px !important;}
```

- i should note that:
  bxSlider uses 100% width to keep stuff responsive so you might get a distorted image by forcing the height, and that is why you need to serve pre-sized images to the slider (just to fix the height issue..)
- solution:
  use media queries to set a different height when viewed in mobile (just a suggestion)

best of luck...

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me, and allows you to keep responsiveness

```
    .bx-wrapper, .bx-viewport, .bx-wrapper img {max-height: 200px !important;}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved centering and fixed size with these lines

```
.bx-wrapper img {
height: 400px;
max-width: auto;
display: inline;
```

}

Comment: doesn't help with centering :(

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend wrapping it with a `div` then adjusting the `div`'s CSS. Bxslider I believe inherits the height & width.

```
.yourDivClass{
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
}
```

From here you can adjust the `li`'s accordingly:

```
.yourDivClass li {
    background-color:green; //just to see the overflow if height & width isn't equal
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: When I am giving custom padding on li & image last image crop automatically. And slider come blank end of carousels..

Answer (score 0):

Update!

http://jsfiddle.net/u62LR/

Just set your image height...

```
.bx-wrapper, .bx-viewport {
    height: [IMAGE HEIGHT] !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want use !important just make like this

```
.bx-wrapper {
  height: 400px; //Just choose your height
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `max-height`:

```
.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport{max-height: 657px;}
```