# Bxslider - images don't show after first loading of website

Tags: image, bxslider

I've got a problem with bxslider. Everything work just fine except showing images in slider after first loading. They just don't appear. When you refresh the website and wait a while they appear.

The address of website: [PC-DATA](http://pc-data.com.pl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your website code right now when you first load the page the `.bx-viewport` are using some inline styles. One of these inline styles is setting the height of the container to `0`. If you change the height to the size you want it to (in this case I am guessing 460px) then it should show correctly the first time.

```
.bx-wrapper, .bx-viewport {
    height: 460px !important;
}
```

Alternatively you [can see what others did here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18976107/bxslider-setting-height). Hope that helps.